# Conditional data attribute in handlebars template with ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have this, what should be simple, problem in Ember.js. Based on a boolean property, I want to choose whether or not to set a data attribute. This works perfect for class attributes and I can set the data attribute with a property (so in this example {{bind-attr data-toggle="label"}} works).

```
<a href="#" {{bind-attr class="hasContent:dropdown-toggle"}} {{bind-attr data-toggle="hasContent:dropdown"}}>
    {{label}}
    {{#if hasContent}}<b class="caret"></b>{{/if}}
</a>
```

What's the fastest/cleanest solution for this? The object in my template is just a Ember.object.
I'm using Ember 1.5 & Handlebars : 1.2.1

Comment: {{#hasContent}} data-toggle {{/hasContent}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do it like this

```
{{#if hasContent}}
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        {{label}}<b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
{{else}}
    <a href="#">{{label}}</a>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Mhhh indeed, thx, I wasn't thinking straight, that works. But for later reference, is it possible?

Comment: Problem is that other properties does not support the colon syntax. You would need to create a computed property on the bound class.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Why not just use... hasContent:dropdown-toggle:no-content-null-class-name-you-make-up

Comment: Because this syntax is only supported for `class` property as far as I know.